# Calculating the coordinates of a point on circle, along a line between the center of the circle and another point outside it?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

Here's an image to demonstrate the question:

[image]

Let's say I have `Point A` at `[0,0]`, and `Point B` at `[50, 30]`. I want to find the coordinates of `Point X`, along a circle of radius `15`, with an origin at `Point A`, which is also on a line between `Point A` and `Point B`.

Pointers on the best method to do this?

Comment: Compute the distance from A to B. Divide that by the radius, then multiply that ratio by the AB vector to get the AX vector.

Comment: Best in what sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this has been tagged JavaScript, here's a simple implementation:

```
// disclaimer: code written in browser
function Point2D(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function findCircleInteresction(center, radius, target) {
    var vector = new Point2D(target.x - center.x, target.y - target.y);
    var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vector.x, 2) + Math.pow(vector.y, 2));
    var normal = new Point2D(vector.x / length, vector.y / length);
    var result = new Point2D(center.x + (normal.x * radius), center.y + (normal.y * radius));
    return result;
}

findCircleInteresction(new Point2D(0, 0), 15, new Point2D(50, 30));
```

`Point2D` is just a class to make objects with `x` and `y` properties.
`findCircleInteresction` takes three parameters:
 - `center` the center of the circle
 - `radius` the radius of the circle
 - `target` a point **outside** the circle

In `findCircleInteresction`:
 - calculate the `vector` between the `center` and the `target`
 - get the `length` of the resulting `vector`
 - compute the `normal` (normalized) of the `vector`
 - find the point where the vector intersects with the circle by adding the center of the circle plus the normalized vector components multiplied by the radius of the circle

This code could be heavily optimized and it's untested but I think it illustrated the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to think of this as two overlapping triangles, one with sides `Bx-Ax` and `By-Ay`. What you want is to find the coordinates of `X`, which would specifically be a triangle with sides `Xx-Ax` and `Xy-Ay` but with known hypotenuse `R`, which is your radius of the circle. Notice that the angle for both triangles are equal in respect to the x-coordinates-axis.

So to get the angle of the triangle, take the `arctan(By-Ay/Bx-Ax)` Now with that angle, call it `T`, you can solve for the smaller legs with your know radius `R`.

To get the x coordinate you would take `Rcos(T)`

To get the y coordinate you would take `Rsin(T)`

Bringing it all together you have that `Xx = Rcos(T)` and `Xy = Rsin(T)`

If you are not willing to use a Math library, which this method would use, you can use ratio's (as `Pointy` commented)